# curl: read headers from file

Tags: curl

After the --dump-header writes a file, how to read those headers back into the next request?  I would like to read them from a file because there are a number of them.

I tried standard in: `cat headers | curl -v -H - ...`

I'm actually using the feature in Firebug to "Copy Request Headers" and then saving those to a file.  This appears to be the same format.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

## Since curl 7.55.0

Easy:

```
$ curl -H @header_file https://example.com
```

... where the header file is a plain text file with an HTTP header on each line. Like this:

```
Color: red
Shoesize: 11
Secret: yes
User-Agent: foobar/3000
Name: "Joe Smith"
```

## Before curl 7.55.0

curl had no way to bulk change headers like that from a file. They had to be modified one bye one with `-H`.

Your best approach with an old curl version is probably to instead write a shell script that gathers all the headers from the file and use them, like:

```
#!/bin/sh
while read line; do
  args="$args -H '$line'";
done
curl $args https://example.com
```

Invoke the script like this:

```
$ sh script.sh < header_file
```

Comment: can you add an example of the header file? i'd like to see the format. how to put in strings, null, bool, int, float; where to use quotes. i just keep getting this as a search result so I think it would help people

Comment: Added. But really exactly how each header is supposed to look like or contain depends entirely on that specific header...

Comment: @DanielStenberg it would be really useful if you could add the above `header_file` example to the docs https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#-H

Comment: @icc97 coming... https://github.com/curl/curl/pull/10455

Comment: Now visible at https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#-H =)

Answer (score 63):

how about this:

```
curl -v -H "$(cat headers.txt)" yourhost.com
```

where `headers.txt` looks like

```
Header1: bla
Header2: blupp
```

works in BASH.

Comment: Works in curl 7.22.0.  I added a space so it would be 'bla bla' and I could not trip it up.  This command was esier to test with `curl -v  -H "$(cat headers.txt)" google.com` .. Lets see if anyone else comments to make sure this is a safe way to do it.  It is not documented.

Comment: I explicitly stripped the `-v` before since I thought it's noise that's not adding to a correct answer, but you're right, it is easier. so I added it back

Comment: But it works more or less by coincidence since it feeds it in as a single header with embedded newlines. IMHO, A cleaner version would have a -H on each line in the headers.txt file too and leave it out from the command line.

Comment: I like this hack for its elegance, but there's one tiny problem: because headers are not explicitly listed individually, they don't override any default headers sent by curl. Result: duplicate headers. E.g. if you have a custom content-type header, combined with -d, you now send two, possibly conflicting, content-type headers.

Comment: This will work, HOWEVER, keep in mind that in a process listing (such as `ps aux`), the expanded variable may be seen by other users. *SO*, if you are providing credentials or auth-token in the header, this approach will _expose the credentials_ to other users - which would be unacceptable.

Answer (score 28):

Starting with curl 7.55.0 it can now read headers from a file:

```
curl -H @filename
```

It's that easy now.

Comment: Ok, but what's the syntax?

'header':'info'
"header":"info"
header:info

or some other combination? I can't seem to find the right combination.

Comment: Chris, the syntax is the same as in CLI - "name: value", no quotes, 1 header per line. You can test what is sent by using -v flag: `curl -v -H @test.txt test.com` to see how it's actually sent and compare with `-H 'x: y' -H 'a: b'` - you should see identical output from curl as long as your `test.txt` contains 2 lines: `x: y` and `a: b`.

Answer (score 14):

As answered by [@dmitry-sutyagin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3952027/dmitry-sutyagin), if your curl is at least version 7.55.0 you can use the `@` notation to read headers from a file:

```bash
curl -H @headerfile.txt https://www.google.com/  # requires curl 7.55.0
```

If your curl is NOT 7.55.0 or newer, there's a useful hack:

- Use the option `-K/--config <config file>`, and put several `-H/--header <header>` lines in the text file.

For instance:

1. `curl --dump-header foo.txt https://www.google.com/`
2. If necessary, `dos2unix foo.txt`
3. Convert the file to `-H 'header'` lines, manually or with a script:

   ```bash
   cat foo.txt |
     awk '$1 == "Set-Cookie:"' |
     perl -ne "chomp; next if /^\\s*\$/; if (/'/) { warn; next } print \"-H '\$_'\\n\";" |
     tee headerfile.txt
   ```

   This might output something like:

   ```bash
   -H 'Set-Cookie: 1P_JAR=2018-02-13-08; [...]'
   -H 'Set-Cookie: NID=123=n7vY1W8IDElvf [...]'
   ```
4. `curl --config headerfile.txt https://www.google.com/`

Comment: Using the default curl 7.54.0 on macOS Mojave, I had to use double quotes instead of single quotes in the config file, otherwise I got warnings about unescaped whitespace and the headers weren't set at all

Answer (score 5):

```
curl $(xargs -a headers.txt printf "-H '%s'") example.org
```