# How to read headers from file using cURL?

Tags: linux, shell, curl

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12661159/1197775).

And I wrote this variant:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line ; do
  headers="$headers -H '$line'"
done < public/headers.txt
echo $headers
curl -X PUT \
     $headers \
     -d @'public/example.json' \
     echo.httpkit.com
```

In `headers.txt` I have:

```
X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID:123
X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD:123
```

But when I run `./public/curl.sh` I am not getting the headers I am sending.

I isolated the issue with an env var:

```
$ x='-H some:asd'
$ curl $x echo.httpkit.com
=> header was NOT present
$ curl -H 'some:asd' echo.httpkit.com
=> header was present
$ curl -H some:asd echo.httpkit.com
=> header was present
```

How can I correctly insert a variable in the header section?

Comment: How do you know the header is present or not? I'm checking with `curl -v $x echo.httpkit.com 2>&1 >/dev/null | grep some:` and it matches, looks like the header is there just fine. What is your ``curl --version` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's ask [shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.net/):

```
In yourscript line 3:
  headers="$headers -H '$line'"
                       ^-- SC2089: Quotes/backslashes will be treated literally. 
                                   Use an array.
```

Ok, then let's do that:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line ; do
headers=("${headers[@]}" -H "$line")
done < public/headers.txt
echo "${headers[@]}"
curl -X PUT \
   "${headers[@]}" \
   -d @'public/example.json' \
   echo.httpkit.com
```

Result:

```
{
  "method": "PUT",
  "uri": "/",
  "path": {
    "name": "/",
    "query": "",
    "params": {}
  },
  "headers": {
    "host": "echo.httpkit.com",
    "user-agent": "curl/7.35.0",
    "accept": "*/*",
    "x-paypal-security-userid": "123",      //      <----- Yay!!
    "x-paypal-security-password": "123",
    "content-length": "32",
    "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  },
  "body": "\"This is text from example.json\"",
  "ip": "127.0.0.1",
  "powered-by": "http://httpkit.com",
  "docs": "http://httpkit.com/echo"
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to put the HTTP headers on a command line (perhaps for security reasons), you can still have curl read them directly from a file.

```bash
curl -H @headerfile.txt https://www.google.com/  # requires curl >=7.55.0
```

If your curl is older than 7.55.0:

- Use the option `-K/--config <config file>`, and put several `-H/--header <header>` lines in the text file.

For more details, please see my answer in the original article:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/48762561/5201675