# how do I hide curl arguments from command line?

Tags: linux, shell, curl

I have a cronjob that runs this command:

```
curl -s -G -H Authorization: Bearer ${mysecret} ${myurl}
```

I'm a ding dong--I just realized everyone can see my password when they issue a "ps -ef | grep curl". I tried using the -d option, but was unsuccessful. Do you know how I can hide the value for $mysecret?

Comment: You could ditch shell and curl and use a language like python or perl that have a http user agent library.

Comment: Put the command in a script and call the script from the cronjob.

Comment: @TravisClarke that won't work, people will still be able to see the curl password by running the ps command.

Comment: [How to run cron jobs with sensitive data?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46848054/608639).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See [curl - Read headers from file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24541379/curl-read-headers-from-file). You've got two options.

1. For new versions (7.55 and newer) of curl:

   curl -H @*filename* ${myurl}

   Where *filename* holds header and the secrets: Authorization: Bearer *mysecret*
2. For older versions create a config file:

   curl -K *filename* ${myurl}

   Where *filename* holds the option: -H "Authorization: Bearer *mysecret*"

Comment: Please note, that the double quotes in the second option are important. When I skip them or use single quotes, authentication fails.