# Login and post using curl in one command

Tags: http, unix, authentication, curl

I am configuring a solar device on the field that runs a small web server to upload data to a web service.

However the web service needs to have authentication and ssl. There is a way to configure an upload url endpoint but not a way to save the headers to a file etc.

Is it possible to login pass the headers to the next request and post data all in one request?

Something like

`curl -d "email=sadf@yahoo.com&password=asds&submit=Login" --dump-header headers http://localhost:3000/users/login **>** curl -X POST http://localhost:3000/test --data-urlencode point="<status>A note</status>"  -H 'Content-Type: application/xml`'

Comment: sometimes saving the session cookies from the login to a file  and replaying them in the next request is all that is needed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [read header file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12661159/read-header-file)

Comment: Added some more details about why it needs to be one command